# fwrite user DB info to file during Install

Tags: php, installation, fwrite

Im trying to create an installation wizard for my app. In one of the steps im trying to write/store the users connection details to a file. Does anyone know of a better way to do this. My code obviously breaks when it reaches the $ symbol.

```
    $myFile = "../functions/config2.php";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

    $stringData = "<? #DATABASE CONNECTIONS\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);

    $stringData = "$dbservertype='mysql';\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);

    $stringData = "$servername='".$_POST['host']."';\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);

    $stringData = "$dbusername='".$_POST['dbusername']."';\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);

    $stringData = "$dbpassword='".$_POST['dbpass']."';\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);

    $stringData = "$dbname='".$_POST['dbname']."';\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);

    $stringData = "global $link;\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);

    $stringData = "$link=mysql_connect ('$servername','$dbusername','$dbpassword');\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);

    $stringData = "if(!$link){die('Could not connect to MySQL');}\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);

    $stringData = "mysql_select_db('$dbname',$link) or die ('could not open db'.mysql_error());\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);

    fclose($fh);
```

I would like the written file to end up looking something like this

```
    <?
    //DATABASE CONNECTIONS
    $dbservertype='mysql';
    $servername='posted_server';
    $dbusername='posted_user';
    $dbpassword='posted_pass';
    $dbname='posted_dbname';

    global $link;
    $link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbusername","$dbpassword");
    if(!$link){die("Could not connect to MySQL");}
    mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
    ?>
```

My output right now looks like this

```
    <? #DATABASE CONNECTIONS
    ='mysql';
    ='host';
    ='user';
    ='pass';
    ='dbname';
    global ;
    =mysql_connect ('','','');
    if(!){die('Could not connect to MySQL');}
    mysql_select_db('',) or die ('could not open db'.mysql_error());
```

Comment: Some further suggestions. Avoid the short tags <? rather use full <?php, and you should also avoid the mysql_* functions as they are deprecated, read through [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using double quotes "
in php if you include something that is a valid variable name in double quotes, php will interpolate that variable, and if it doesnt exist, it will resolve to nothing, or throw an error. [See here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

You should escape the $ sign eg:

```
$stringData = "\$dbservertype='mysql';\n";
```